# Sci-fi story referenced in The Practice Effect

Tags: story-identification

In David Brin's *The Practice Effect* (published 1984), the main character references

> a science-fiction story he had once read in which a minute change in electrical conductivity resulted in a tenfold increase in human intelligence.

The story is not named, however.

Is this referencing a real story, or just a genre-aware thought by the main character?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Only Brin knows for sure, but an obvious candidate is [Brain Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_Wave) by Poul Anderson.

The Earth had been travelling through a region of space where an "energy field" had been reducing the conductivity of all all conductors including the brain. When the Earth emerges from the field the conductivity increases and a side effect is that all animals with a brain become more intelligent.

From the book:

> Corinth had been working on the determination of electrical constants. For the metals they were the same, or nearly the same, as before, but the resistivity and permittivity of insulators had changed measurably—they had become slightly better conductors.
>
> Except, in the precision apparatus, such as Gertie the computer, the change in electromagnetic characteristics was not enough to make any noticeable difference. But the most complex and delicately balanced mechanism known to man is the living cell; and the neurone is the most highly evolved and specialized of all cells—particularly that variety of neurones found in the human cerebral cortex. And here the change was felt. The minute electrical impulses which represented neural functioning—sense awareness, motor reaction, thought itself—were flowing more rapidly, more intensely.

Comment: Not one I've run across before, but that seems highly likely to be it.  I'll give the question some time to see if anyone else has suggestions or an actual quote from Brin, though.

Comment: @Bobson It's The Practice Effect, so if you keep reading this answer it'll get better.  ;)